# how to reference t1 without making a new column for t2

Tags: postgresql

So this is the first query t1 i added employee id from this query

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
    FROM 
(SELECT 
     employeeid, concat(firstname,' ',lastname) AS fullname 
 FROM 
     employees ) t1
```

then i like to join this query

```
JOIN (
      SELECT employeeid as orderemp,COUNT(customerid) AS ordertaken, COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS
             uniquecustomercount, 
             from orders  GROUP BY employeeid, orderid
             ) t2 ON t1.employeeid = t2.orderemp
```

for context i am making a view

id like to make this view without repeating the employeeid column

Comment: You show `select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*` so how do plan to add in table `t3`?  In meantime why not `t1.employeeid = t2.employeeid`. As long as you table qualify the column name you can reuse it.

Comment: Btw, are you sure you want to group `t2` also by `orderid`?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `t2.*` but spell out the columns you want in the view:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.ordertaken,
  t2.uniquecustomercount,
  t3.*
FROM (
  SELECT employeeid, concat(firstname,' ',lastname) AS fullname 
  FROM employees
) t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    employeeid as orderemp,
    COUNT(customerid) AS ordertaken,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS uniquecustomercount, 
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY employeeid, orderid
) t2 ON t1.employeeid = t2.orderemp
```

or simpler

```
SELECT
  t1.employeeid,
  concat(t1.firstname,' ',t1.lastname) AS fullname,
  t2.ordertaken,
  t2.uniquecustomercount,
  t3.*
FROM employees t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    employeeid as orderemp,
    COUNT(customerid) AS ordertaken,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS uniquecustomercount, 
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY employeeid, orderid
) t2 ON t1.employeeid = t2.orderemp
```

Another alternative is to use `USING` in the `JOIN` clause which causes only one column to be generated:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT employeeid, concat(firstname,' ',lastname) AS fullname 
  FROM employees
) t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    employeeid,
    COUNT(customerid) AS ordertaken,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS uniquecustomercount, 
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY employeeid, orderid
) t2 USING (employeeid)
```

Comment: Where is `t3.*` coming from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver From the OPs code :-) I guess there's more `JOIN` clauses in the query that they haven't shown